# Display issues: Xrandr, uncaimed monitor, non-existent external monitor

Tags: nvidia, xrandr, bumblebee

I'm not sure exactly what the issue is here, it's manifesting as a few things.

1. I can't change the resolution of my monitor.
2. Neither flux not redshift can change the display colour balance.
3. I'm have NVidia and Intel onboard graphics, currently NVidia is active with Bumblebee, but I can't run anything with optirun.

I have in the past had an external monitor plugged in via VGA which I no longer use, everything seemed to work perfectly and now with just my laptop things don't work :/

What I've tried:

- deleting ~/.config/monitors.xml
- checking nvidia-settings (has no options)
- apt-get purge nvidia-* bumblebee and reinstalling
- reinstalling xserver

Nothing has worked so far.

Info:

```
$ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)


$ uname -a
Linux gulch 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080       0.0*
```

I have two Xlogs, I'm pretty sure the Xlog8 is the pertinent one since that's what's specified in bumblebee.conf, but I'll post both here just in case:

Xlog0: http://pastebin.com/4XgQ7GGk

Xlog8: http://pastebin.com/r58xTQJ5